# What is location of built in SQL functions and Oracle Packages in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to know location of file / table where definition of Built In Functions / Packages / Procedures of Oracle are stored like MAX(), DBMS_OUTPUT etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the PL/SQL engine, the Oracle supplied functions such as `MAX()` are part of the package `STANDARD` in the `SYS` schema.

Most other supplied packages reside in the `SYS` schema, however you can find out where any individual package is located quite easily - [for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12064):

```
SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name = 'DBMS_OUTPUT'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12064/0)**:

```
|  OWNER | OBJECT_NAME | SUBOBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_ID | DATA_OBJECT_ID | OBJECT_TYPE |                       CREATED |                 LAST_DDL_TIME |           TIMESTAMP | STATUS | TEMPORARY | GENERATED | SECONDARY | NAMESPACE | EDITION_NAME |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    SYS | DBMS_OUTPUT |         (null) |      4972 |         (null) |     PACKAGE | August, 27 2011 08:22:22+0000 | August, 27 2011 08:22:22+0000 | 2011-08-27:08:22:22 |  VALID |         N |         N |         N |         1 |       (null) |
| PUBLIC | DBMS_OUTPUT |         (null) |      4973 |         (null) |     SYNONYM | August, 27 2011 08:22:22+0000 | August, 27 2011 08:22:22+0000 | 2011-08-27:08:22:22 |  VALID |         N |         N |         N |         1 |       (null) |
```

The following documentation page lists off most (if not all) PL/SQL supplied packages:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/intro.htm#BABGEDBH

Answer (score 1):

The scripts to create the build-in functions, packages and procedures are stored on the database server machine. You have to find the value of the environment variable `$ORACLE_HOME`, and then go to `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/`. Just use grep to find the file you're looking for.

If the database server is a Windows machine, look at `ECHO %ORACLE_HOME%` at the command prompt and proceed from there.